# Sql Plus package information

Tags: oracle, package, sqlplus

Is there  a way in SQLPLUS to get information about certain package when it was created and all that. For example if there is a package name Pack_Employee.. how can I get date of creation, size etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ALL_OBJECTS or USER_OBJECTS table that describes all objects accessible to the current user.

**Oracle Reference Documentation**

- [ALL_OBJECTS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2005.htm#i1583352)

  select object_name, object_type, last_ddl_time, timestamp, status, created
  from user_objects
  where object_name IN ('Pack_Employee');

Comment: Just a potential gotcha here: typically objects in Oracle are created with upper case naming unless explicitly set otherwise by the use of double quotes when creating the object. More often than not, you should reference object_name in upper case or else compare on upper case: **WHERE UPPER(object_name) = 'PACK_EMPLOYEE';**

Answer (score 0):

As @Joël pointed out, you can get the creation date, last DDL date and status from `ALL_OBJECTS`.  Size, however, is a much trickier question. The best approximation I can come up with for size is to get the length of each line of source, which will give you the size in characters:

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(text)) as char_size, COUNT(*) as line_count
FROM   all_source s
WHERE  name = 'YOUR_PACKAGE' AND TYPE = 'PACKAGE BODY' AND owner = 'YOU';
```

Comment: Could you use the data dictionary view USER_OBJECT_SIZE to determine the size PL/SQL objects? http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4376.htm#sthref2263

Comment: @carpenteri: It really depends on what you mean by "size" in this context.  In at least some cases, the `source_size` column of `USER_OBJECT_SIZE` is exactly the same as the result of my query above. Also, `USER_OBJECT_SIZE` takes a considerable amount of time to run, so it's probably not a view you want to visit very often.